# Chrome Auto Fill Form Bug

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I have looked in to this and can't find out why - anyone have any ideas?

[This screenshot is of the form](http://cl.ly/image/1G201e2w3s0j)

`<input size=5 name="months_at_address" value="" type="text" placeholder="Months" class="small" />`

The above code is the input populating with 'United Kingdom'

[Here is a link to the website](http://www.dacexchange.co.uk)

The form code starts on line 246, Postcode starts on line 378 - effecting the input on line 408.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your input field something else which doesn't include "address". Chrome's autofill feature relies on regex to determine if an input field is asking for a firstname, lastname, address and so on. months_at_a would probably do the trick. I think the autofill regex would recognize months_at_adr as an address field as well.